# action script 3.0 in adobe animate cc , how to solve click go on the web page

Tags: actionscript-3, adobe, animate-cc

when I test movie in adobe animate the function of button fb can directly go to the fb page but when I export to the .swf file it cannot go to fb page i do not know how to solve this issue someone help this is my project...

Comment: Did you run the SWF by just double-clicking it? For security reasons a SWF alone does not open web links. Put it online, embedded in a web page and then test again. PS: If you really need to run it from hard drive then you need to [add the folder of the SWF under "Trusted Locations"](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html#117502) . Make sure Flash is enabled when you view the link to see the **Settings** menu. Can also try right-clicking on your running SWF and go to **Settings** to see same options.

Comment: Right click to the SWF file?

Comment: Yes, you double-click the left mouse button to **run the SWF** so a Flash Player window opens showing your Flash app, okay? So click the other button (like when you want to save a picture in the browser), click somewhere on the app and you'll see a settings option...

Comment: still did not have function hmm